# How can I change the field background color in Gtk2 entry?

Tags: c, colors, gtk

GTK+ v2 in C using Code::Blocks on Win7.

I am using the "insert_text" signal for a callback to an entry widget.

Inside the callback function, how do I change the entry field background color?

I think this is not the same as changing the widget color.

My code:

The Callback...

```
static void VerifyDOW (GtkEntry    *entry,
                          const gchar *text,
                          gint         length,
                          gint        *position,
                          gpointer     data)
{
GtkEditable *editable = GTK_EDITABLE(entry);
const gchar *result = gtk_editable_get_chars (editable, 0, -1); // = g_new (gchar, length);
int i, count = strlen(result);

    for (i=0; i < count; i++) {
        if ((! isdigit(result[i])) & (result[i] != ',')) {
            i = count;
            g_signal_handlers_block_by_func (G_OBJECT (editable), G_CALLBACK (VerifyDOW), data);

            /* CHANGE FIELD, NOT WIDGET, COLOR HERE */

            g_signal_handlers_unblock_by_func (G_OBJECT (editable), G_CALLBACK (VerifyDOW), data);
        }
    }
    g_signal_stop_emission_by_name (G_OBJECT (editable), "insert_text");
    g_free (result);
}
```

Now in Main()...

```
        entry = gtk_entry_new();
        gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text (entry, "Valid input, 1..7 and ,");
        gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry), "1,3,5");

        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "insert_text", g_CALLBACK(VerifyDOW), NULL);

        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), entry...
```

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try gtk_widget_modify_base:

```
GdkColor color = {0, 255<<8, 220<<8, 220<<8};
gtk_widget_modify_base(GTK_WIDGET(entry), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
```